# Cannot create a jsTree inside of a jQueryUI tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jstree

I am not able to create a jsTree inside of a jQuery UI tab. If I create the jsTree outside of the tab, it works fine. Does anybody know if jsTree is incompatible with jQuery UI tab?

My page is below. If I replace the following line

```
var treeContainer = jQuery("#tabTree");
```

with:

```
var treeContainer = jQuery("#pageTree");
```

Then the tree loads fine in the page underneath the tab control.

```
<body>
    <div id="myTabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="tab1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="tab2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="tab3.html">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="pageTree"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>         
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsTree/jquery.tree.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
        $(function(){

            $("#myTabs").tabs();

            var treeContainer = jQuery("#tabTree");
            var treeData = {
                data: {
                    type : "json",
                    opts : {
                        static : [
                            {
                                data: "A node",
                                children: [
                                    { data : "Child node 1" },
                                    { data : "Child node 2" },
                                    { data : "Child node 3" }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]

                    }
                }
            };
            treeContainer.tree(treeData);
        });     
    </script>
</body>
```

Here are the contents of tab3.html:

```
<div id="tab3Container">        
    <div id="tabTree"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show us some code?

Comment: @Justin Ethier: Updated question with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content in those tabs isn't present until you click the tab to load it, so the selector `jQuery("#tabTree")` doesn't have anything to match, no elements matching that selector exist yet.  You need to run this code when that ajax page is loaded, like this:

```
var treeLoaded = false;
$("#myTabs").bind( "tabsload", function(event, ui) {
  if(!treeLoaded && jQuery("#tabTree", ui.panel).length) {
    var treeContainer = jQuery("#tabTree");
    var treeData = {
        data: {
            type : "json",
            opts : {
                static : [
                    {
                        data: "A node",
                        children: [
                            { data : "Child node 1" },
                            { data : "Child node 2" },
                            { data : "Child node 3" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]

            }
        }
    };
    treeContainer.tree(treeData);
    treeLoaded = true;
  }
});
```

The `tabsload` event, [described here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-load), runs when ajax content is loaded.  The code above checks if your `id="tabTree"` was in that loaded content, and if so and the tree hasn't been built yet, builds it.